# What is the meaning of the sequence ك ه ي ع ص

Tags: quran, tafseer

As a Baha’i’, I do not practice Islam, but I do read the Qur’an. I am curious about the Islamic interpretations of the this sequence of letters from the surah «Mary.» It is the first Aya, if memory serves.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences like this are called the Huruf al-Muqatta'at. You can research that. There are different views on its meaning:

- It is from the *mutashaabihaat* and its meaning is only known to Allah.
- It means the sequence of letters themselves. They are being sworn upon, similar to how other things are sworn upon.
- The letters stand for some names/attributes of Allah. For example it is reported that:

  - Kaaf stands for **K**afee or **K**abeer or **K**areem or Mala**k** ,
  - Haa stands for **H**aadi or **H**aad or Alla**h**
  - Yaa stands for **Y**ameen or for ***Y**ujeeru wala yujaru Aaalayhi* or for  ***Y**adu Allahi fawqa aydeehim* or Am**ee**n or Hak**ee**m or Az**ee**z  or Rah**ee**m
  - Ayin stands  for **'A**alim or **'A**zeez or **'A**zeem or **'A**lee or **'A**dl
  - Saad stands for **S**adiq or **S**amad or Mu**s**awwir

  It can then mean that Allah is Sufficient, Guide, Protector, All-Knowing and Truthful in His promise etc.
- It is  by itself a name of Allah. Or each letter is by itself a name of Allah.
- It is a name of the Quran.
- It is a name of the Surah.

**Ref:** [Mawsoo‘ah at-Tafseer al-Ma’thoor](https://shamela.ws/book/639/9385), [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura19-aya1.html#qortobi), [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura2-aya1.html#katheer),  [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura19-aya1.html#baghawy) etc.